# Find the position difference between two transformations of a line

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

I am trying to find the new position of the points in a line, after certain changes.

The line is simple: coordinate locale (0,0) to (len, 0); it has a position in the scene, and a rotation.

If rotation is applied, the line changes visually, but the position doesn't... The rotation is stored in the rotation transformation, along with shifts for x and y.
That allows me to determine the true position of the end points of the line, P1 and P2 ... the program I use has even functions:

`P1 = mapToScene(0,0)` and `P2 = mapToScene(len,0)`

I think formulas would be

$P1 = pos.x - \frac{len*sin(\theta)}{2}$

$P2 = pos.y + \frac{len*(1 - cos(\theta))}{2}$

Changing the length of the line would change P2, but not P1, while rotation would change both.

What I am struggling to find out is, formulas for
- changing `P1` while keeping `P2` constant, and
- changing `P2` while keeping `P1` constant

**How can I determine the change in position in the two cases ?**

What I can determine:

I can find the length and angle of the original line ($len_1$, $\theta_1$)
Given a new P1, I can determine the length and angle of the line between the new `P1` and `P2` ($len_2$, $\theta_2$).
But from there, I keep trying to find the difference between the old and new position (since the line will still be an object horizontal line, of length $len_2$ and a transformation with angle $\theta_2$).

**Edit** I have been unable to use transformations as suggested in comment, but after multiple redraws of what the moves would look like, I fixed the formula for determining the position shift for a change in `P1` - so `P2` change will be next.

$dx = \frac{len_1*(1+\cos(\theta_1))}{2} - \frac{len_2*(1+\cos(\theta_2))}{2}$
$dy = \frac{len_1*\sin(\theta_1)}{2} - \frac{len_2*\sin(\theta_2)}{2}$
$pos.x += dx$
$pos.y += dy$

It almost works... It works when $\theta_1$ is 0...

For changing P2 and keeping P1 constant, it would seem the solution is even simpler:
- From the current transform, involving a rotation, take the translation coefficients
- create a transform for the new rotation
- move `pos` by the difference

Very simple... Very logical... But it only works once (subsequent transforms all change points).

I am close to drawing the conclusion that this is an unsolvable problem.

Comment: How's your linear algebra?  It sounds like you're dealing with scale, translation, and rotation transforms.  Translations have no fixed points, but scales and rotations fix the origin.  To keep some particular point fixed under a rotation or scale, you would typically conjugate the rotation or scale with a translation that moves the desired fixed point to the origin.

Comment: @AaronGolden Interesting suggestion, I am trying to apply reverse transform (I updated my question) - but like with everything I have tried, all points seem to move...  A possible cause: the transform I must apply to the object rotates around center, but if I apply transforms to keep P2 (or P1) constant, the shift will be wrong... I just can't find a way to mix them... This may just be one cause of the "wrongness". Also - not quite clear on your statement "scales and rotations fix the origin" - do you mean they can be applied on a different origin ?

Comment: Try reversing the order of your translations, translate -dx, -dy, then rotate, scale, etc. then translate back by +dx, +dy.  Does that fix the point at dx, dy relative to the origin?  You're looking for a composition something like this:  [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C+0%2C+x%7D%2C%7B0%2C+1%2C+y%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D*%7B%7Bcos%28t%29%2C-sin%28t%29%2C0%7D%2C%7Bsin%28t%29%2Ccos%28t%29%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D*%7B%7B1%2C+0%2C+-x%7D%2C%7B0%2C+1%2C+-y%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D*%7Bx%2Cy%2C1%7D).

Comment: @AaronGolden I don't quite get what you are saying... This is what I understand: If I perform a single transformation (for example translate, rotate, translate back) the `pos` does not change but the resulting matrix will contain translating coefficients. It is what I use to apply transformations for all objects (with or without scaling). What I need: values to translate the `pos` so that replacing the old transform with a new transform will leave a point unchanged - a point that is **not** used as anchor in any of the transforms.